# List Fridays and Saturdays in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using excel formulas, there is a date `2023-03-01` in cell K6 and in cell E11 I put the following formula for Fridays

```
=IF(MONTH($K$6-MOD(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)-6,7)+IF(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)<6,7,0)+7*(INT((ROW()-11)/2)))=MONTH($K$6),$K$6-MOD(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)-6,7)+IF(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)<6,7,0)+7*(INT((ROW()-11)/2)),"")
```

And in cell E12, I put the following formula for Saturdays

```
=IF(MONTH($K$6-MOD(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)-7,7)+IF(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)<7,7,0)+7*(INT((ROW()-11)/2)))=MONTH($K$6),$K$6-MOD(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)-7,7)+IF(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)<7,7,0)+7*(INT((ROW()-11)/2)),"")
```

And the formulas are working well for the date in cell K6 `2023-03-01`

But when changing the date in cell K6 and making it `2023-04-01`, I got an empty return in E11 as the month started as Saturday `2023-04-01`. Is it possible to make the formula flexible so as not to get an empty result at cell E12 or E12?

I can adjust the formula in E11 to work with both Fridays and Saturdays

```
=IF(MONTH($K$6-MOD(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)-6-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR($K$6),MONTH($K$6),1),1)=7,1,0),7)+IF(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)<6,7,0)+7*(INT((ROW()-11)/2)))=MONTH($K$6),$K$6-MOD(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)-6-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR($K$6),MONTH($K$6),1),1)=7,1,0),7)+IF(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)<6,7,0)+7*(INT((ROW()-11)/2)),"")
```

But as for cell E12 is not adjusted.

This is my try in cell E12

```
=IFERROR(IF(MONTH($K$6-MOD(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)-IF(ISNUMBER(E11),7,6)-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR($K$6),MONTH($K$6),1),1)=7,1,0),7)+IF(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)<IF(ISNUMBER(E11),7,6),IF(ISNUMBER(E11),7,6)+1,IF(ISNUMBER(E11),7,6))+7*(INT((ROW()-11)/2)))=MONTH($K$6),$K$6-MOD(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)-IF(ISNUMBER(E11),7,6)-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR($K$6),MONTH($K$6),1),1)=7,1,0),7)+IF(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)<IF(ISNUMBER(E11),7,6),IF(ISNUMBER(E11),7,6)+1,IF(ISNUMBER(E11),7,6))+7*(INT((ROW()-11)/2)),""),"")
```

but not accurate in results.

Comment: Are you trying to get the closes Friday/Saturday or what?

Comment: Simply I need the Fridays and Saturdays of a specific date (month). To be listed in one column. My problem now is with the second cell E12 only.

Comment: So your input is just one date and then you want Excel to dinamically list all Fridays and Saturdays of the month of your input?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes, exactly

Comment: Something like https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3455-excel-list-all-mondays.html?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is that I need both Fridays and Saturdays in one column and I could solve it as I explained in my question (review the formulas and the question again please)

Comment: Ple0ase add a screenshot of exactly what you want for results given the data 1-Apr-2023 in K6  and also for 1-Mar-2023 in K6

Comment: Already solved and there is a screenshot in Foxfire's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got Excel 365 try this:

```
=TEXT(FILTER(SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(A4,0)),,EOMONTH(A4,-1)+1,1),WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE (DAY(EOMONTH(A4,0)),,EOMONTH(A4,-1)+1,1),1)>=6),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

[image]

Shorter version:

```
=LET(alldates,SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(A4,0)),,EOMONTH(A4,-1)+1,1),TEXT(FILTER(alldates,WEEKDAY(alldates,1)>=6),"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

Even sorther thanks to @Jvdv

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(33,,EOMONTH(A4,-1)),FILTER(x,(MONTH(A4)=MONTH(x))*(WEEKDAY(x)>5)))
```

Comment: Shorter: `=LET(x,SEQUENCE(33,,EOMONTH(A4,-1)),FILTER(x,(MONTH(A4)=MONTH(x))*(WEEKDAY(x)>5)))`. Drop `TEXT()` as it would turn numbers into text. One should use number formatting =)

Comment: @JvdV pretty cool. I'm still getting used to E365 because I have limited access to it.

Comment: You'll find it's fun! =)

Answer (score 2):

Away from Excel 365
Here's the solution
In cell E11

```
=IF(MONTH($K$6-MOD(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)-6-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR($K$6),MONTH($K$6),1),1)=7,1,0),7)+IF(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)<6,7,0)+7*(INT((ROW()-11)/2)))=MONTH($K$6),$K$6-MOD(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)-6-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR($K$6),MONTH($K$6),1),1)=7,1,0),7)+IF(WEEKDAY($K$6,1)<6,7,0)+7*(INT((ROW()-11)/2)),"")
```

And in cell E12

```
=IFERROR(IF(MONTH(IF(WEEKDAY(E11)=6,E11+1,IF(WEEKDAY(E11)=7,E11+6,"")))>MONTH($K$6),"",IF(WEEKDAY(E11)=6,E11+1,IF(WEEKDAY(E11)=7,E11+6,""))),"")
```